# How does Task Scheduling in ASP.NET USing C# works

Tags: c#, asp.net, backgroundworker, job-scheduling

I want to import csv file with huge records in In MS SQL,
I should be able to upload any files, the moment I upload it should start inserting data and once it is done notify me on the page.

I have logic to import data from CSV to MS SQL and its working fine, but i am able to do only one file at a time.

i want parallel background processing on those uploaded file and and signaling on its successful completion

I am very new to .NET kindly help me Step by step, it would be awesome if you can explain with logical example

Thank you.

Comment: use Ajaxfileupload control if you want to upload multiple file at a time. Also there are many other options you can use.

Comment: @KrunalPatil I think it involves much more than just uploading multiple files at once, for instance: parallel/background processing, possibly transactions, signaling the client for a 'Its done' message. Not just a multiple-file-uploader.

Comment: @Maarten, agreed to what you said, but the question ain't clear enough. Its totally opinion based, at first he need to be able to upload multiple files, that's what i think, later we can help him process them simultaneously. OP haven't mentioned he was able to upload multiple file or not.

Comment: Maarten is right
i want parallel background processing on those uploaded file and and signaling on its successful completion

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for background (BG) services to handle such processing for you, typically you should avoid processing bulk data in asp.net (web application)

Implementation of a BG service and a messaging queue would be your ideal solution. So your asp.net (web app) code will be responsible to initiate upload of a file and trigger the processing via queuing up a message to the BG service. And later on the processing of csv files would be done by the BG service as per the queue.

In the implementation of BG service you can also choose to process synchronously or simultaneously that depends on your project needs.

**Using MSMQ sample**

In your webapp after uploading the file add the following code to send a message to the queue

```
const string queueName = @".\BGQueue";
if (!MessageQueue.Exists(queueName))
    MessageQueue.Create(queueName);

MessageQueue messageQueue = new MessageQueue(queueName);
messageQueue.Label = "BG processing queue";

messageQueue.Send(fileName, "File to process");
```

Windows service code

```
const string queueName = @".\BGQueue";
MessageQueue messageQueue = new MessageQueue(queueName);
Message[] messages = messageQueue.GetAllMessages();

foreach (System.Messaging.Message message in messages)
{
    //process the message, insert/update SQL etc.
}
messageQueue.Purge(); //cleanup the queue once done.
```

**Concept example (one of my past implementation) (not a good one)**

- Create a message table in DB with columns to store file name, status and priority if needed
- Webapp will upload the file and insert a record in message table with status ToDo
- Create a windows service which run a timer every x minute or second to poll the message table
- With every poll the service will load next ToDo message(s) from the db and mark the status In Progress
- the service will then process (insert/update SQL) and once complete then it will either update the record status to Done or remove the record

This is merely a concept for you, I hope this concept may help you implement your strategy. If you need some code samples, I may create some for you but might take some time

Comment: Pushpraj, you are right, i need in that way, can you provide me any such dummy example.

Comment: -1 self rolled Message bus on RDBMS. NEVER write a ESB in a RDBMS!

Comment: thanks @Aron, I just mentioned one of my past implementation. There are couple of messaging techniques like MSMQ are available to choose from. And just for the sake of information one of the leading company (~$800m) is running its product based on the mentioned example. I would not simply judge an solution based on theory. The mentioned solution currently serves background tasks for over 100K customers daily including buck insertions, report generations etc. But it is again up to the need to choose the right strategy.

Comment: @PushprajRuhal $800Mil is not a huge company. Plus it is my experience the larger the company the more WTF you find. Since they have had more time to build legacy code. I stand by my comment, as RDBMS use the wrong CAP model to be effective as an ESB solution. Just search IPC over Database. Much of the work you end up doing is to transform the CAP model to something that is usable, and every solution I have seen uses highly vendor specific SQL, which is extremely slow (for the RDBMS).

Comment: @Aron I accept the fact you just mentioned, I'll update the answer with more appropriate example. Thanks for the same :)